# Is Mono 2.10.4+ compatible with Mac OS X PowerPC?

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, powerpc

Has anyone built Mono 2.10.4 or later for Mac OS X PowerPC? The latest binary release with PPC support I can find from Ximian is 2.10.3, but recent versions of MonoDevelop (2.8 - 3.0, which  don't appear to contain anything Intel-specific) only support 2.10.4 and later.

If nobody can point me to a binary, I'll have a go at building it myself, but I just want to make sure that's not going to be a fruitless effort first.

Since PPC Linux builds of later versions are available and Mac OS X 10.5 support is still in the latest versions, it *should* work, right?

Comment: It most likely will, you're right with your assumptions. However, building Mono is not always trivial. The instructions on http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_OSX are terribly outdated.

Comment: @skolima, even in latest Mono 3.0 release notes, fixes for PowerPC build are mentioned, http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0, so I think the PowerPC port is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

For most people that want to build on Mac OS X, I would suggest:

```
git clone git://github.com/xamarin/bockbuild.git
cd bockbuild/profiles/monodevelop-mac-dev
./monodevelop-mac-dev -b
```

I'm not certain this will work on 10.5, but it should work on at least 10.6 (or if not, try an older git revision from, say, 6 months or a year ago)

Hope that helps.